# Bug on wordpress with chrome in localhost?

Tags: apache, google-chrome

I am deploying a synchronized web enviroment with WAMP and Google Drive. For one reason I want that the Apache server uses the port 8080. Well, but if a put a wordpress website in the apache main folder, it does not work in Chrome, but yes in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

The point is that in Chrome when i do:

localhost:8080/my-wp

it redirect me to

localhost/my-wp

And then it does work beacause my apache server is running in port 8080.

Is it a bug or i can solve that in chrome settings?

Comment: What if you use IP instead of `localhost` ?

Comment: If i use 127.0.0.1:8080 also it does not work.